# Where statement with order by rand function not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a data table of prospect clients in three categories

1. Hot
2. Cold
3. Not Specified

Now what I am trying to do is that when the user clicks on "Hot Leads" the system will fetch 5 random records from prospect client data categories under "HOT".

Below is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';
require 'logincheck.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['uiduser']);
$fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['fullname']);

if(isset($_GET["q"])) {


// posted data
$query_q = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['q']);
$status="Fresh";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM adv_leads WHERE adv_type='".$query_q."' AND 
adv_status='".$status."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){}else{ echo "error";}


while($build = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
echo '<tr class="select">';
              echo '<td>'.$build['adv_uid_leads'].'</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
}}
?>
```

Here

```
q= Type of lead i.e.HOT, COLD
Status= Fresh Leads
```

If I remove `WHERE` clause system is working fine but with `WHERE` clause it return "0" results.

Answer (score 0):

friend may I know the value of your database, because whenever you use 
`"adv_type='".$query_q."'"` , it will check the exact match , instead of that you can use like into your query

eg :

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM adv_leads WHERE adv_type LIKE'%".$query_q."%' AND 
adv_status='".$status."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
```